# Replacing an expansion valve with a piston to improve efficiency?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

Could you replace an expansion valve in a refrigeration system with a piston to get useful work out of the expansion of the fluid between the high side and the low side?

If so, why does this not seem to be done in practice in air-conditioning units to, say, drive a fan off the expansion? Or is it?

Comment: This is most likely an engineering consideration rather than a physics one. Such an addition would likely be quite costly for only a small gain in efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. The extra complexity and costs may make this feature not worth the stretch in some circumstances. Nevertheless, it can create significant energy savings.

It is mostly a subject of research and development at the moment.

See for example:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1876610215027897